# Array filtering on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, internet-explorer

I have a list that dynamically updates based on if certain sections are available.

I'm creating two arrays based on data-attributes and comparing them for differences. In other words, in my list if there are no data-letters matching the section letters than give it a background.

It works great except on Internet Explorer. In IE11 they all get a red background and I don't know why. You can see this in action here:

```js
$(function() {
 var attrFilterItemArray = new Array();
  $(".atoz li a").each(function() {
    var attrItem = $(this).data("letter");
    attrFilterItemArray.push(attrItem)
  });

  var attrTitleArray = new Array();
  $(".letter-list__authors-titles, .letter-grid__authors-titles").each(function() {
    var attrTitle = $(this).data("title");
    attrTitleArray.push(attrTitle)
  });

  var compareTitleFilter = attrFilterItemArray.filter(function(n) {
    return !this.has(n)
  }, new Set(attrTitleArray));

  for (var i = 0; i < compareTitleFilter.length; i++) {
    $(".atoz li a").each(function() {
      var letter = $(this).data("letter");
      if (letter == compareTitleFilter[i]) {
        $(this, "#filter li a").addClass("filter-item--disabled").parent().addClass("filter-item--disabled").addClass("title-unavailable");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.filter-item--disabled {
  background-color: red;
}

.alphabet {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="filter" class="atoz letter-list__author-nav">
    <li><a data-letter="#" href="#" class="filter-item">#</a></li>
    <li><a data-letter="a" href="#" class="filter-item">a</a></li>
    <li><a data-letter="b" href="#" class="filter-item">b</a></li>
    <li><a data-letter="c" href="#" class="filter-item">c</a></li>
</ul>

<section data-type="title" data-title="#" class="letter-list__authors-titles">
<span class="alphabet">#</span>
</section>
<section data-type="title" data-title="a" class="letter-list__authors-titles">
<span class="alphabet">#</span>
</section>
<section data-type="title" data-title="c" class="letter-list__authors-titles">
<span class="alphabet">#</span>
</section>
```

In my research I found that [Set() is not supported in IE.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) I changed that piece to:

```
  var compareTitleFilter = attrFilterItemArray.filter(function(n) {
    return !attrTitleArray.includes(n);
  });
```

But then the disabled class never gets added.

Which is seen in the fiddle. But it still does not work in IE. I could not find any viable alternatives or polyfills to help complete the job.

How can I get this array/data-attribute filter to work in IE?

Comment: it's IE11. I haven't tested this on older ones and it's not necessary.

Comment: Does IE11 support the includes method in your filter function?

Comment: Side note, your first two usages of `each()` are prime examples of where `map()` can be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Array.prototype.includes()` is not supported in any version of IE. See [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). You can test the old way, using `indexOf`:

```
var compareTitleFilter = attrFilterItemArray.filter(function(n) {
    return attrTitleArray.indexOf(n) === -1;
});
```